# Gensim 3.8.3 Word2Vec is not updating the weights/parameters on a toy dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to train word2vec model on a simple toy dateset of 4 sentences.
The Word2vec version that I need is:

- Skip-gram model
- no negative sampling
- no hierarchical soft-max
- no removal or down-scaling of frequent words
- vector size of words is 2
- Window size 4 i.e all the words in a sentence are considered context words of each other.
- epochs can be varied from 1 to 500

**Problem that I am facing is:** No matter how I change the above parameters, the word vectors are not being updated/learned. The word vectors for epochs=1 and epochs=500 are being same.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nltk

# toy dataset with 4 sentences
sents = ['what is the time',
         'what is the day',
         'what time is the meeting',
         'cancel the meeting']

sents = [nltk.word_tokenize(string) for string in sents]

# model initialization and training
model = Word2Vec(alpha=0.5, min_alpha =0.25, min_count = 0, size=2, window=4,
                 workers=1, sg = 1, hs = 0, negative = 0, sample=0, seed = 42)

model.build_vocab(sents)
model.train(sents, total_examples=4, epochs=500)

# getting word vectors into array
vocab = model.wv.vocab.keys()
vocab_vectors = model.wv[vocab]
print(vocab)
print(vocab_vectors)

#plotting word vectors
plt.scatter(vocab_vectors[:,0], vocab_vectors[:,1], c ="blue")
for i, word in enumerate(vocab):
    plt.annotate(word, (vocab_vectors[i,0], vocab_vectors[i,1]))
```

The out put of `print(vocab)` is as below

`['what', 'is', 'time', 'cancel', 'the', 'meeting', 'day']`

The output of `print(vocab_vectors)` is as below

```
[[ 0.08136337 -0.05059118]
 [ 0.06549312 -0.22880174]
 [-0.08925873 -0.124718  ]
 [ 0.05645624 -0.03120007]
 [ 0.15067646 -0.14344342]
 [-0.12645201  0.06202405]
 [-0.22905378 -0.01489289]]
```

The plotted 2D vectors [image: Here!]

**Why do I think the vectors are not being learned?** I am changing the epochs value to 1, 10, 50, 500... and running the whole code to check the output for each run. For epochs = #any_value <1,10,50,500>, the output (vocab, vocab_vectors, and the plot) is being same for all the runs.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you've determined that the vectors don't change. Can you expand your code, with textual output, that demonstrates what you're observing? (You may be testing for change wrong.)

Comment: Hi, I have added the output for the print statements and plot to the question above. I am changing the values of epochs to different values like 1, 50, 500.. and printing/plotting the word vectors. For all the runs with diff epochs value.. the output is being same.

Answer (score 0):

By providing the parameters `negative=0, hs=0`, you've disabled both training modes, and no training is happening.

You should either leave the default non-zero `negative` value in place, or enable the non-default hierarchical-softmax mode while disabling negative-sampling (with `hs=1, negative=0`).

Other thoughts:

- Enabling logging at the INFO level is often helpful, and might have shown progress output which better hinted to you that no real training was happening
- Etill, with a tiny toy dataset, the biggest hint that all training was disabled – suspiciously instant completion of training –  is nearly indistinguishable from a tiny amount of training. Generally, lots of things will be weird or disappointing with tiny datasets (& tiny vector sizes), as word2vec's usual benefits really depend on large amounts of text.
- Lowering `min_count` is usually a bad idea with any realistic dataset, as word2vec needs multiple varied examples of a word's usage to train useful vectors – and it's usually better to ignore rare words than mix their incomplete info in.
- Changing the default `alpha`/`min_alpha` is also usually a bad idea – though perhaps here you were just trying extreme values to trigger any change.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!..Its learning if I "turn on" either negative sampling or hierarchical soft-max. Basically, Its a small toy dataset, so I wanted use simple softmax rather than negative sampling or hierarchical soft-max. So in gensim word2vec, there is no option to use simple softmax??

Comment: Plain softmax is so much slower than these options that it wasn't an option in the original `word2vec.c` code that Google released, and thus also wasn't added to the Gensim implementation (which started as a very direct port of that code).

Comment: Okay, Thank you. Also, in this case, vector size is 2 and I can scatter plot the data without having to use t-SNE. Is there any way to plot the word vectors for each iteration/epoch. Basically, how to visualize the word embeddings learning process as the epochs are increasing?

Comment: Are there any other implementations/libraries which allows simple softmax?

Comment: If you need to look at interim results, the `.train()` methoh takes a `callbacks` parameter, to which you can supply the right kind of object (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html#gensim.models.callbacks.CallbackAny2Vec), & receive a call at the end of each training epoch. You could conceivably save aside the interim data you need at each such callback.

Comment: Most implementations follow original precedent of only offering the usefully-fast modes. (Why would you want something that's many multiples slower, and also not quite what most people mean when they say 'word2vec'?) I think I may have seen a plain-softmax option in Facebook's FastText implementation, which is similar to (and with certain options disabled nearly identical to) word2vec - but I doubt that'd offer the callbacks, too. If you pieced together an implementation from a neural-net library (perhaps even via one of their examples), you might be able to choose a plain-softmax optimizer.